# sudoers: NOPASSWD in same line as PASSWD:ALL?

Tags: sudo

Is this combination legal:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/foo, PASSWD:ALL
```

or do they conflict or cancel each other out?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [`sudoers` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) I would say that you can do them together:

```
Tag_Spec
  A command may have zero or more tags associated with it.  There are eight
  possible tag values, NOPASSWD, PASSWD, NOEXEC, EXEC, SETENV, NOSETENV,
  LOG_INPUT, NOLOG_INPUT, LOG_OUTPUT and NOLOG_OUTPUT.  Once a tag is set on 
  a Cmnd, subsequent Cmnds in the Cmnd_Spec_List, inherit the tag unless it 
  is overridden by the opposite tag (i.e.: PASSWD overrides NOPASSWD and 
  NOEXEC overrides EXEC).
```

The `PASSWD:ALL` will override the `NOPASSWD` afterwards. There is even an example that shows what you're trying in the man page.

> By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself
>   before running a command. This behavior can be modified via the
>   NOPASSWD tag. Like a Runas_Spec, the NOPASSWD tag sets a default for
>   the commands that follow it in the Cmnd_Spec_List. Conversely, the
>   PASSWD tag can be used to reverse things. For example:

```
ray     rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, PASSWD: /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm
```

#### References

- [man page for sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)